# Yii2 - Валидатор на изменение данных

Tags: yii2

А как можно сделать валидатор на запрет изменения данных? Актуально для апи

Comment: Зачем в форму добавлять данные которые не нужно изменять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишите своё правило валидации для полей. Минимальный пример реализации [здесь](https://toster.ru/q/282582)
но вообще лучше будет не добавлять в форму те данные которые не нужно изменять

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['name', 'notModifyValidator']
    ];
}

/**
 * Валидатор проверки изменения аттрибута.
 *
 * @param $attribute
 * @return bool
 */
public function notModifyValidator($attribute)
{
    if ($this->isAttributeChanged($attribute)) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'ТЕКСТ ОШИБКИ');
        return false;
    }
}
```